# Is possible replace a plist file when my iPhone app is running?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

is possible replace a plist file when my iPhone app is running? I'd like to implement backup into my app (into the backup zip I have also the plist file) and I don't understand how can I replace the plist file with its backup.

Comment: -1 Too vague. *Which* plist? What backup? If you're referring to NSUserDefaults, you might be able to get away with calling [NSUserDefaults synchronize] (to flush changes), restoring the file to Library/Preferences/, and calling [NSUserDefaults synchronize] again. I'm sure NSFileManager has an appropriate rename/move method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the original plist into App's resources such that it is signed & delivered with your app on install.

Then, detect if it exists in the `Documents/` directory and copy it there if not.  If you need to replace it, simply copy anew from your App's resources.